# Why doesn't `list::iterator + 1` work?

Tags: stl, iterator

```
std::list<CPoint>::iterator iter= vertices.end();
CPoint point = *(iter+1);
```

In such cases I've tried to assign to variables the value of `(iter-1)` or `(iter+1)`. Why doesn't it work? whereas `iter++` or `iter--` works.

Comment: where is iter from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, these operations are not part of the `iterator` definition. You can use the `std::advance()` function for that.

Obviously, the `operator+(int)` could be overriden to do that, just as `operator++()` is, but probably it is not, because this operation is not guaranteed to be of constant complexity, and a syntax like `(iter + n)` could suggest otherwise.

From [`advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

> **Complexity:** Linear. However, if `InputIt` additionally meets the requirements of `RandomAccessIterator`, complexity is constant.

Comment: But will it work if I want to assign `+1` the value of the iterator to another iterator? i.e `iter2=iter+1`? Since `std::advance` increments the iterator being passed to it, won't `iter2=std::advance(iter,1)` increment `iter` and then assign the incremented value to `iter2`. How should I make it assign +1 the   value of the iterator without incrementing the original iter itself?

Comment: @Ghost: Easy... something like `iter2=iter; std::advance(iter2, 1);`. 8-) Naturally, if you want to advance just one, you can also do: `iter2=iter; ++iter2;`